# Selenium Chrome Driver - Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I have an issue running tests using Selenium and Chromedriver.

System: Windows 10.

Browser: Chrome 81.0.4044.113.

ChromeDriver: 81.0.4044.69.

JDK: 14.0.1.

Selenium Client: 3.141.59.

IDE: IntelliJ (with Maven).

Things I've done:

- updated JDK version.
- ran chromedriver.exe via cmd and then, verified http://localhost:{port}/status is available.
- updated chromedriver + chrome browser.
- Restart system.

Needless to say that none of the above worked.
I would appreciate some help with this one, I've been trying to fix it on and off for the past couple of weeks with no success.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'L1000121335', ip: '10.0.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 
'10.0', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: CustomChromeWebDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.driverutils.CustomChromeWebDriver.<init>(CustomChromeWebDriver.java:15)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.driverutils.DriverFactory.setChromeLocalDriver(DriverFactory.java:71)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.driverutils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:41)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.SeleniumTestBase.startUpBrowser(SeleniumTestBase.java:55)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.SeleniumTestBase.concreteBeforeMethod(SeleniumTestBase.java:44)
at com.ge.miconnect.automation.testngutils.TestBase.beforeMethod(TestBase.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:683)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:510)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:26576/status] to be available after 20003 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 46 more
```

Edit:

**SeleniumTestBase**

```
public abstract class SeleniumTestBase extends TestBase {

    protected ExtendedWebDriver driver = null;

    public void concreteBeforeMethod(ITestContext context) {
        String givenRunner = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("runner");
        String givenBrowser = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser");
        startUpBrowser(givenBrowser, givenRunner);
    }

    private void startUpBrowser(String browser, String runner) {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriver(browser, runner);
    }
}
```

**DriverFactory**

```
public class DriverFactory {
    public static ExtendedWebDriver getDriver(String browser, String runner) {
        ExtendedWebDriver driver = null;
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        MutableCapabilities browserCapability = setDesiredCapabilitiesByBrowserName(desiredCapabilities, browser);
        if (runner.contentEquals("local")) {
            if (browser.contentEquals("firefox"))
                driver = setFirefoxLocalDriver((FirefoxOptions) browserCapability);
            if (browser.contentEquals("chrome")) {
                assert browserCapability instanceof ChromeOptions;
                driver = setChromeLocalDriver((ChromeOptions) browserCapability);
            }
        }
        if (runner.contentEquals("remote")) {
            try {
                String url = "placeholderURL";
                System.out.println("Create RemoteWebDriver of " + desiredCapabilities.hashCode());
                driver = new CustomRemoteWebDriver(url, browserCapability);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }
    private static CustomChromeWebDriver setChromeLocalDriver(ChromeOptions options) {
        String path = null;
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
            path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/../selenium-tester/drivers/chromedriver.exe";
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX)
            path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/selenium-tester/drivers/chromedriver";
        assert path != null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
        return new CustomChromeWebDriver(options);
   }
}
```

**CustomChromeWebDriver**

```
public class CustomChromeWebDriver extends ExtendedWebDriver {
    public CustomChromeWebDriver(ChromeOptions options) {
        this._driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
}
```

**ExtendedWebDriver**

```
public class ExtendedWebDriver {
    protected WebDriver _driver;
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and include the Java code used to initialize the web driver?

Comment: yes add your driver class code

Comment: @GregBurghardt - Per your request, I added the required code.